# How can I get GHC to warn about incomplete pattern bindings in do blocks?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following Haskell program is broken, because it does an incomplete pattern binding:

```hs
main = do
  [x] <- pure ["foo", "bar"]
  print x
```

If you compile it, you'll get no warnings:

```
$ ghc -fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns -o example example.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( example.hs, example.o )
Linking example ...
```

but if you run it you'll get:

```
example: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at example.hs:2:3-5)
```

I would like to somehow get a compiler warning.

From the documentation, I would have thought `-fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns` would do it, since the `do` block desugars to:

```hs
desugared = pure ["foo", "bar"] >>= \[x] -> print x
```

And indeed, adding that to the example file does produce a warning:

```
$ ghc -fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns -o example example.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( example.hs, example.o )

example.hs:1:37: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a lambda abstraction:
        Patterns not matched:
            []
            _ : (_ : _)
```

How do I get a similar warning when I do the same thing inside a `do` block?

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
```

Comment: Note that incomplete patterns with `<-` end up calling the `fail` function of that monad. So at least in old versions of Haskell the code isn't per se wrong, there could be valid results: `Prelude> let {x::[Int]; x = do {[y] <- return [1,2]; return y}}
Prelude> x
[]
`  Or changing `x :: [Int]`  to `x :: Maybe Int` you get `Nothing`.

Comment: Indeed, fixing this would require to know when `fail` is returning bottom, which is tricky. I'd still want `[ f x | Just x <- list ]` and the equivalent `do Just x <- list ; return (f x)` not to trigger warnings. Not sure how one can realistically achieve this...

Comment: I propose you file a GHC feature request for `-fwarn-implicit-fail` or similar that warns when desugaring inserts a call to `fail` that wasn't in the source.

Comment: I think the expectation is that when you use `<-` in that way you know what you are doing and are accept that `fail` may get called. After all, you can only specify a single pattern so you should know if the pattern is exhaustive or not. It's also a very convenient feature - the pattern `Just ... <-` alone appears several hundred times in Hackage. It would be interesting to see the original discussion that went on when it was added to GHC - I'm sure the pros and cons were extensively debated.

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5813 "Offer a compiler warning for failable pattern matches"

Answer (score 1):

As for now, the only thing you can do in order to avoid bugs due to this quirk is to avoid monads with `MonadFail` instance (in recent GHC versions incomplete bind patterns would then lead to a compilation error).

[There is already an issue for this](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/5813). There is also a statement defending this solution stating that it may be something completely desirable and therefore does not deserve a warning:

> This is actually the right useful behavior. using things like
>
> ```
> do
>   Just x <- xs
>   Just y <- ys
>   return (x,y)
> ```
>
> will do the right thing, failing if xs or ysresults in Nothing. for
> instance, in the list monad, it will create the cross product of the
> non Nothing members of the two lists. a parse monad may backtrack and
> try another route, the IO monad will create a useful (and
> deterministic/catchable) exception pointing to the exact file and line
> number of the pattern match. The do notation is the only place in
> haskell that allows us to hook into the pattern matching mechanism of
> the language in a general way.